# How to use a function put in using a constructor

Tags: node.js

So I have this class:

```
class Sigil {
    constructor(name = "", type = "", func = (oppositeCard, oppositeCardLane) => { }) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.function = func
    }

    Activate(oppositeCard, oppositeCardLane) {
        
    };
}

var fly = new Sigil("Fly", "OnAttack", (oppositeCard, oppositeCardLane) => {
    oppositeCard = cardLib.blank;
    return oppositeCard;
})
```

What I wan to do is use that function that I put in using the constructor. So like i want to call the "func" function using the Activate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you do is call `this.function`.

```js
class Sigil {
  ...
  Activate(){
    this.function();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: How do i take teh return value of that function because when i run the code it return undefine

Comment: What you do is set the return value to a variable. e.g. `var variable = this.function();`